# How to find the highest integer in an array without using max()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find the highest number in an array, and I'm having problems doing so.

The code which will help is this:

```
def printing(test1Array,test2Array,test3Array,nameArray,totalArray):
    for i in range(0,3):
        print(nameArray[i], "scored", totalArray[i] ,"in total")
        print("The  average for this person was" , totalArray[i]/3)
    a = sum(totalArray)
    a = a/9
    print("The class average was" , a)
highest(test1Array,test2Array,test3Array,nameArray,totalArray)

def highest(test1Array,test2Array,test3Array,nameArray,totalArray):
    bestPerson = totalArray[i]
```

If you want me to add more of my code please say so.
The highest function at the end is what I need help with.
Thanks.

Comment: What's the reason for the artificial "without using max()" restriction?

Comment: Though ravindar has answered the literal question in your title, the code you've posted appears not to be relevant to it. Could you supplement your question with some expected inputs and outputs? What sorts of values will be assigned to `testnArray`, `nameArray`, `totalArray`? What do you expect your program to do with these values?

Answer (score 2):

```
def highest(a):
  max = a[0]
  for i in a:
    if i>max:
        max = i
  print max


highest([1,2,3,10,5])
```

**o/p**
10

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a list

```
x = [1, 25, 2]
```

you can do

```
y = sorted(x)
print(y)
>>> [1,2,25]
```

and to get max

```
y[-1]
```

PS: Mine is a generalised solution you can use it to your effect. But one question, why dont you want to use max()?

Comment: `y[-1]` does the same thing like `y[len(y)-1]`

Comment: @julivico thanks, I had never tried it. Thanks for teaching though:P

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, if you don't want any in-built functions:

```
def highest(test1Array,test2Array,test3Array,nameArray,totalArray):
    bestPerson = totalArray[0]
    for i in totalArray:
        bestPerson = i if i>bestPerson else bestPerson
    return bestPerson
```

Though I don't know why you're passing the other arrays to `highest`, assuming it is a function to return the highest value in `totalArray`

Answer (score 1):

U can try like this.

```
a = [1, 23, 4]
max_value = 0
for i in a:
    if i > max_value:
        max_value = i
print max_value
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `Python 3` then you can try this using the inbuilt `max`

```
array = [1, 3, 4, 12, 4, 7]
    def get_maxnum(given_array):
    maxnum = max(given_array)
    return maxnum
print("max num is ",get_maxnum(array))
```

> output: 12